# PHP get advanced array information

Tags: php, arrays

I try to get the data from the array. My code is:

```
print_r($result['Header']);
```

The result is:

```
header 
@LOC = 1,
@USERNAME = Tom,
```

My problem is: I don't get the @Username for my function.
You can see my code above. But i think you guys have a better idea how to solve this easy problem.

I was looking for a solution but i don't get it. @PHP.net i cant find anything with arrays what is similar to my problem. Sorry for my bad English.

Thank you! :)

Comment: So that is saying that `$result['Header']` contains a newline delimited string, so the contents of that array item is a string. So look up the [String Functions in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) I would start by looking at the [explode() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use `preg_match_all` to parse data and `array_combine` for bind values to variable names:

```
preg_match_all('/@(\S+) = ([^,]+),/', $result['Header'], $matches);

$vars = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

print_r($vars);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [LOC] => 1
    [USERNAME] => Tom
)
```

[Test preg_match_all online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/null/php/php8/603e7cd9b6638f595e19431223eca2d6/)

Comment: Thats it! THANKS! :)

Comment: Hey, preg_match_all does many spaces, when i print_r vars.. what can i do?